# UiPath Get Text crashes robot

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I'm trying to get a text from a textfield with Get Text, but in some cases this field is optional and the robot crashes because it doesn't have anything in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options. It's hard to say which one fits best you so here is a pool of **possible solutions**:

1. when **NOT** using the **Modern Design**, you can easily use the `Element exists` activity, [self explaining](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/ui-element-exists)
2. if you use the **Modern Design** and miss old activities like `Element exists`, go to the filter dropdown and select `Show Classic`, this way you are now also able to choose `Element exists`

   [image: Activities filter]
3. you could also wrap such failing activities into a `Try Catch`, then your process wont fail, but a `Try Catch` should always be the last way out
4. when using the **Modern Design**, you can try `Find Element`, if the returned object is empty you know that it was not found, make sure to set a proper Timeout here, otherwise you wait for 30 seconds
5. but on your case it could be better to use an `Image exists` or `Find Image Matches` as you said you are looking for text in a textfield, just inverse it and look for an empty textfield, and if you have no matches all is fine

But to be honest, I would go for the `Element exists`. Give this a try, but be aware that in the future this activity might be replaced by something else and your process will need a little bit of rework.